# Determine calling node inside JavaFX change listener

Tags: java, javafx-2

I need to perform validation on several TextFields when text is changed. The validation is exactly the same, so I thought I use a single procedure. I can't use **onInputMethodTextChanged** because I need to perform validation even when control does not have focus. So I added a **ChangeListener** to **textProperty**.

```
private TextField firstTextField;
private TextField secondTextField;
private TextField thirdTextField;

protected void initialize() {
    ChangeListener<String> textListener = new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                String oldValue, String newValue) {
            // Do validation
        }
    };

    this.firstTextField.textProperty().addListener(textListener);
    this.secondTextField.textProperty().addListener(textListener);
    this.thirdTextField.textProperty().addListener(textListener);
}
```

However, while performing validation, there is no way to know which TextField triggered the change. How can I obtain this information?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two ways:

Assuming you only register this listener with the text property of a `TextField`, the `ObservableValue` passed into the `changed(...)` method is a reference to that `textProperty`. It has a `getBean()` method which will return the `TextField`. So you can do

```
StringProperty textProperty = (StringProperty) observable ;
TextField textField = (TextField) textProperty.getBean();
```

This will obviously break (with a `ClassCastException`) if you register the listener with something other than the `textProperty` of a `TextField`, but it allows you to reuse the same listener instance.

A more robust way might be to create the listener class as an inner class instead of an anonymous class and hold a reference to the `TextField`:

```
private class TextFieldListener implements ChangeListener<String> {
  private final TextField textField ;
  TextFieldListener(TextField textField) {
    this.textField = textField ;
  }
  @Override
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
    // do validation on textField
  }
}
```

and then

```
this.firstTextField.textProperty().addListener(new TextFieldListener(this.firstTextField));
```

etc.

Comment: to avoid `ClassCastException`, I think you can expect `Control` rather than `TextField` and check if the `Control` is a `TextField`, something like `if(mControl instanceof TextField) ((TextField) mControl).doSomething()`

Comment: I want to give a more general solution. This will work with StringProperty,, BooleanProperty etc.: `((ReadOnlyProperty<?>)observable).getBean()`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void changed(ObservableValue observableValue, Object o, Object n) {
    try {
        StringProperty textProperty = (StringProperty) observableValue ;
        TextField textField = (TextField) textProperty.getBean();

        if (textField == textFieldChannel1) {

        } else if (textField == textFieldChannel2) {

        } else if (textField == textFieldChannel3) {

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **valueProperty** instead ;)

```
this.firstTextField.valueProperty().addListener(textListener);
this.secondTextField.valueProperty().addListener(textListener);
this.thirdTextField.valueProperty().addListener(textListener);
```

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't look like valueProperty() exists for a TextField.

Answer (score 0):

It has a simple solution.

```
public void setListener(TextField textField) {
    BiConsumer<TextField, String> check = (tField, newValue) -> {
        // Do validation
    };
    textField.textProperty().addListener((ov, o, n)->check.accept(textField, n));
}
```